# Currency converter that works with a single form field

Tags: web-apps, currency-converter

I’ve used Google Search for converting currencies, but this is no longer an option as it (since some time) requires JavaScript for displaying the result (without JS, the result is visible only for a second).

I’m looking for an alternative that

- is a hosted Web app
- does not require an account
- does not require JavaScript
- takes it input from a single form field (see example below)
- shows the result (after form submission) without having to scroll or click somewhere

It has to be a single form field because I want to use it with the [Firefox search shortcut feature](https://superuser.com/a/854673/151741). This allows me to enter my query directly into the Firefox address bar.

Google Search allows queries like `10,50 USD in EUR`, which works great, but a solution does not have to use this same syntax.

It should work whether `.` or `,` is used as decimal mark (I won’t enter a thousands separator).

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a service (“hosted web app”), not software? [We don't do those](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic). I think http://xe.com/ could work for you, its home page requires JS but you can link directly to e.g. `http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=42&From=SEK&To=EUR`

Comment: @Gilles: I’m not sure I follow. The linked Meta discussion is about hosting recommendations, but I’m *not* looking for a hoster (where I could install a currency converter), but for an online currency converter (i.e., hosted by someone else, like Google Search or Wolfram Alpha), so the Meta discussion [Are web service recommendations off-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44/60) would apply here ([unless](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/191/60) such currency converters would be considered to be web *sites* rather than web apps).

Comment: As per http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44, you're in the “whose server shall I run it on” bucket, since you're not looking for software, you're looking for someone to provide you with the service.

Comment: @Gilles: Wouldn’t the ["whose server shall I run it on?" bucket](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/45/60) require that I have/know the software that I want someone to host? -- Asking for a local currency converter would be on-topic, asking for a self-hosted currency converter would be on-topic, but asking for a hosted currency converter would be off-topic? I can’t see why that would be the case.

Comment: +0. Why don't you just use an extension such as NoScript to enable JavaScript while you're using Google Web Search?

Comment: @unforgettableid: I’m using NoScript to *block* the JavaScript used by Google Search. Temporarily allowing it (for every currency conversion query) is too bothersome, and I don’t want to allow it permanently. I guess a custom script could help in this specific case, but I’d prefer not having to install something for achieving this.

Comment: @unor: It seems that you want to use Google Web Search itself (and not, say, [Blackle](http://www.blackle.com/), which can do Google web searches for you), but not to allow Google's JavaScript to run on your machine when you do web searches using their search engine. 1. Why not use Blackle instead for your web searching needs? 2. Why don't you want Google's JavaScript to run when you do web searches on the Google website?

Comment: @unforgettableid: 1. It requires JavaScript, localized versions don’t seem to be available, it’s way slower for me, it doesn’t offer the additional features (like currency conversion, metadata in the sidebar etc.) even if JS is enabled, it’s not transparent that is uses the same index (i.e., not excluding a site), and if I’d want the page to be black, I’d use a custom stylesheet instead of relying on a third party. 2. The comments to this question seem to be the wrong place to explain my motivation for blocking most JavaScript on the Web, including Google’s ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

Wolfram Alpha can convert currencies. It only requires JavaScript for more advanced operations and queries, like currency trends and interactive graphs. I just tried it with JS disabled. Below are the results

[image]

Features:

- Hosted
- Account not mandatory
- Does not require JavaScript for simple currency conversion
- Takes input from a single field
- Shows result directly below input field
- Has a [Firefox Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wolfram-alpha-google/) for displaying results in Google search

Cons:

- It only recognizes a period `.` for decimal separation